# Azure MySQL database error The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, wcf-data-services

This my first time creating application using Azure cloud. I have successfully deployed WFC application   into Azure cloud server, and I also created one Azure Database for MySQL servers. Im able to access the Database from my local PC. But im getting problem when my WFC server communicating with my Mysql DB server, it saying that:

> The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Any suggestion? 
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

This error mainly refers to the TLS version, which relates to Http communication. TLS requires the application SDK support.
At present Azure cloud server often take TLS1.2 protocol as the Http communication protocol. But the client-side application might not be able to support this version of TLS, such as your MySql DB server. Please refer to the below discussion.
[MySQL The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632031/mysql-the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-co)
[The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm ASP.NET C# IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a)
https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/245-resolved-the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate,-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-algorithm.html
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are correct. finally I managed to connect from my server to azure mysql database.